# Find string with regex in text file and replace all other occurrences

Tags: regex, sed, grep

The document I would like to transform looks like this:

```
name=foo
name=bar
thing, attribute1=foo, attribute2=data1
thing, attribute3=bar, attribute4=data2
```

What I would like to do is to find the strings `foo` and `bar` (by searching for "name=(.*)" for example and then to replace all occurrences by adding a prefix.

The document would then become

```
name=prefix_foo
name=prefix_bar
thing, attribute=prefix_foo
thing, attribute=prefix_bar
```

I imagine this could be done purely with `grep` and `sed`?

Working line by line the transformation would be:

```
gsed -i -E 's/name=(.*)/name=prefix_\1/g' test.txt
```

However, how can I reuse the match for other substitutions (recursively)?

Comment: Yes, it looks possible.

Comment: @Andreas and Wiktor: I admit, early morning question, I could add what I tried already, however, I don't think there's an immediate need to be too picky about this question either, the problem is clearly defined.

Comment: Why prefix when a suffix is suffice i.e. `sed 's/\(name\|attribute\)=/&prefix/g' file`

Comment: @potong Only attributes whose value is defined by 'name' should be prefixed, see the edit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed reuse the match for other names. By using the regex options `-P -o`, and making use of `\K`, you can select only the names you want to replace, and then prefix them with `sed`. Here's a bash script that does what you want.

```sh
#get filenames and prefix
echo "input filename?";
read fname;
echo "prefix?";
read prefix;


#if it's a file...
if [ -f "$fname" ]
then
  #grep for names to change
  result=$(grep -P -o "name=\K.*" "$fname");

  #get names in an array
  arrRes=($result);

  #loop through and sed each name
  for name in "${arrRes[@]}"; do
    #name now holds a name to sub
    echo "replacing $name with $prefix$name";

    #sub the name
    $(sed -i "s/$name/$prefix$name/g" "$fname");
  done
fi
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/repls/GrizzledThoughtfulHertz)